# Postgresql query to filter latest data based on 2 columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Table Structure First**

`users table`

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

`sites table`

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

`site_memberships table`

| site_id | user_id | created_on |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |

Assuming higher the created_on number, latest the record

`Expected Output`

| site_id | user_id | created_on |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |

Expected output: I need latest record for each user for each site membership.

Tried the following query, but this does not seem to work.

````
select * from users inner join
      (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (
            PARTITION BY sm.user_id,
            sm.created_on
        ), sm.* 
            from site_memberships sm 
            inner join sites s on sm.site_id=s.id
            ) site_memberships
ON site_memberships.user_id  = users.user_id where row_number=1```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have overcomplicated the problem you want to solve.

You seem to want aggregation:

```
select site_id, user_id, max(created_on)
from site_memberships sm
group by site_id, user_id;
```

If you had additional columns that you wanted, you could use `distinct on` instead:

```
select distinct on (site_id, user_id) sm.*
from site_memberships sm
order by site_id, user_id, created_on desc;
```